# Python - convert string to argument (or dynamically choose increment duration type for date)?

Tags: python, string, date, arguments

Is it possible to convert string to method's argument?

Let say I can get such strings `'weeks'`, `'months'`, `'years'`.

Now I have this:

```
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
from datetime import date

today = date.today()
```

So after this I need to increment `today` by the type of duration that is written in string. For example if string would be provided `'years'`, then it should do this (duration number let say is `10`):

```
some_date = today + relativedelta(years=10)
```

Of course I could do this using ifs and checking what kind of `string` was passed. But maybe there is better way to just convert string to that keyword, so I would not need many ifs for this approach?

Comment: where are  "years" and 10 coming from?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham does it matter where it is coming from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make use of the keyword argument feature of python

```
some_date = today + relativedelta(**{'years': 10})
```

You can also prepare the dictionary before use

```
kwargs = {}
kwargs['years'] = 10
some_date = today + relativedelta(**kwargs)
```

For more information:

- https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-argument
- https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#calls